# ( bathroom van fan ) which wire goes where?

Tags: cables, wire

I bought a basic bathroom van fan, its [Vents 100 S L](https://ventilation-system.com/modification/vents-100-s-l). So I unmounted the old one and replaced the new one on the wall I noticed the cables in the old fan and the new fan are opposite as below :

**old fan**
[image]

**new fan**
[image]

I am not expert in electrical stuff, so didn't want to risk plugging the wire cables. so my questions is :
if the 2 black cables attached the fan are connected in opposite way with the white connector, do you need to change the order of the blue and the brown cables coming from the wall ? so in my new fan, the brown cable should be on the top and the the blue cable on the bottom ?

If you are expert, please advise me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which of the two black wires is connected to blue or brown doesn't matter. This is because it is a AC-motor and will therefore spin the same way no matter how it is connected.